# Presto Plugins: Single JAR vs Multiple JARs

Tags: plugins, presto

- My [`Presto` **plugin**](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop.html) has 2 components: some [`UDF`s](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/functions.html) (for basic `MD5` / `SHA1` *hashing*) and an [`EventListener`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/event-listener.html) (for *logging* queries using `FluentD` logger)
- During development (*single-node* `Presto` cluster), I added them under a single [*Plugin class*](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-spi/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/spi/Plugin.java), bundled a single `JAR` and faced no problem
- During *deployment* I found a pitfall: the **`UDF`s must be registered with all nodes** whereas (my particular) **`EventListener` must be registered only with master node**

---

Now I have two options

**1. Bundle them together in single JAR**

We can control *registration* of `UDF`s / `EventListener`s via external **config file** (different configs for master & slave nodes). As more `UDF`s, `EventListener`s and other `SPI`s are added, a single `JAR` paired with tweaked config file with achieve the desired result.

**2. Bundle them as separate JARs**

We can create different *Plugin classes* for `UDF`s / `EventListener` and provide corresponding **classpaths in `META-INF.services/com.facebook.spi.Plugin`** file through `Jenkins`. We'll then have different `JAR`s for different *components*: one JAR for all `UDF`s, one `JAR` for all `EventListener`s etc. However as more functionalities are added in future, we might end up having lots of different `JAR`s.

---

My questions are

- What are the pros and cons of both techniques?
- Is there an alternate approach?

---

I'm currently on `Presto 0.194` but will soon be upgrading to `Presto 0.206`

Comment: [Here's the link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/xulJogcmFSY) to my query on [`presto-users` *Google group*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/presto-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way works. You can do whichever is easiest for you. There's actually a third option in the middle, which is to have multiple `Plugin` implementations in a single JAR (you would list all implementations in the `META-INF/services` file).

`EventListener` is actually used on both the coordinator and workers. Query events happen on the coordinator and split events happen on the workers. However, if you only care about query events, you only need it on the coordinator.

You can deploy the event plugin on both coordinator and workers but only configure it on the coordinator. The code will only be used if you configure it by adding an `event-listener.properties` file with a `event-listener.name` property that matches the name you return in your `EventListenerFactory.getName()` method.